# compileKotlinIos FAILED - Could not find stdlib

Tags: ios, macos, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to compile kotlin multiplatform, which contains iOS target.
I tried different examples over github, but most of them are outdated and don't work, probably because of incompatibility with current tools. Thing, that seems most reasonable is creating `Mobile Android/iOS | Gradle` or `Mobile Shared Library | Gradle` project using IntelliJ Idea.

When I create brand new project, I am still getting same error:

```
> Task :app:compileKotlinIos FAILED
e: Could not find "stdlib" in [~/git/iosandroidtest, ~/.konan/klib, ~/.konan/kotlin-native-macos-1.3.61/klib/common, ~/.konan/kotlin-native-macos-1.3.61/klib/platform/ios_x64].

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileKotlinIos'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I am using kotlin 1.3.61, xcode 11.3. Any ideas?

Edit:

I pushed empty project (without any changes from me) to github:

https://github.com/hovi/iostest

Comment: Were you running `compileKotlinIOS` command?

Comment: I believe I was.

Comment: For me, that command didn't work.  It asks for the `compileKotlinIosArm64` command instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just ran into a bug with partial archive download.
Per the author there,  "I got a snapshot of the .konan directory. It's interesting as it looks like part of the runtime download is there, but some parts are missing. Specifically in this case the common folder in klib, but also the licenses folder.

I was able to repro this locally by killing the build process while the archive is being extracted. For reference, see NativeCompilerDownloader. It looks to see if the folder is there. If not, it'll download and extract. If yes, the build process assumes everything is OK. ... Their local build will certainly be broken from then on until they clean and rebuild ~.konan." I suggest you report your issue there as well. (btw - tried your project in IJ and AS (as well as creating new lib project in IJ), didn't have any issues. Somehow your bad luck with an interrupted download (:))
[Link to GitHub issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/3415)

Comment: I believe first time when I did build, I ran out of disk space, that has to be it. I deleted `.konan` directoy and build went just fine. Thanks!